# Limits on query string length in grep and grepl?

Tags: r, regex

Working in R, I have a vector of several thousand abbreviated names V. I need to check if any one of these is a substring of a string in vector VS

For a vector of about length 1000, the standard grep works:

```
grep(paste(V, collapse = "|"), VS)
```

However, once V exceeds a certain size (typically 2-4K), I get the following error message:

```
Error in grepl(paste(unique(Unique_Clinic_Distances$v_clinics[1:5000]),  : 
invalid regular expression: 'abc|xyz|123...
```

Is there an upper limit to how long a query string can be with grep and grepl, and if so, is there anything that I can do short of breaking vector V into smaller pieces and querying each one? Alternatively, is there something other than grep and grepl that I can use to check which elements (or any elements) of V are a substring of VS elements?

Comment: You could break it down and check using `sapply`

Comment: I was wondering if there is another approach I could take that doesn't require breaking it down (i.e. grep works just fine if I break the query vector down into components not much more than 1000 long, but this seems like a less than optimal approach)

Comment: You could decide to use `Rcpp` everything is a loop behind the hood. So write the loop in C++

Comment: try using `stringr::str_which` to get grep like result or `stringr::str_detect` for a grepl like result. `stringr` uses a different regex library an does not suffer from these limitations